# class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Tags: android, firebase

- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'

Above are the dependencies which I have added according to my requirement.

Following is the google play service dependency which I am using.
- implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

I have also added the 'apply plugin' statement at the end
- apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Please help me out to solve the error!

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing google services in your build.gradle(root level)?

`build.gradle` root level

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` app level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```