# gradle settings: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Tags: android, gradle

I have read similar Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872053/i-get-an-error-class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzbgl-not-found) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853383/class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzbgl-not-found) about this problem. All solution was to use latest plugins. The question is outdated and I need new configuration using latest versions again. I have checked the plugins compatibility and that all version are up to date when I post this question, but no success yet:

> error: cannot access zzbgl class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

**Project Gradle:**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**app Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I get error when I try to import the followings:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

Comment: Did you try using latest play-services version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.

As quoted from [official docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), you should not use combined play services library. Instead try using specific libraries you need and try updating the specific library to `15.0.1`

Comment: narrowing services to location, solved the problem. But why? Doesn't the combined package include all libraries?

Comment: Yes, it includes all libraries. Not sure why issue comes, but it is strongly recommended to use specific libraries. Great that it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to exclude these classes from Proguard obfuscation:

```
#-dontnote com.google.android.gms.internal.**
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** {com.google.android.gms.internal.** initialize(android.content.Context);}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need be specific to the things that you are using in your app for example if you are using location services instead of using it like this 
"implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.0.0'" 
use it like this 
"implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'"
gradle file (app)