# Class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, google-places-api

I am working on an android app which uses Google Maps and Googla Places API. But after running the project it's getting error like below: 
[See error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC1Zs.png)

Dependencies I have added on the project are:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51695515/6551624) answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

Update the Dependencies version of above lib to to this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
```

Don't add all dependencies remove `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'` use individual dependencies that are needed like `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'`

Comment: Google recommends **not** to use `+` in versions.
>Caution: Using dynamic dependencies (for example, palette-v7:23.0.+) can cause unexpected version updates and regression incompatibilities. We recommend that you explicitly specify a library version (for example, palette-v7:27.1.1).
Quoted above from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup)

Comment: @parekhkruti26 it's one solution,actual it's android studio bug,some time it cause this issue, using above solution it load a latest SDK and it get start working

Comment: It can be a workaround but is not the recommended way.

Comment: @MJM After implementing the above solution, the app doesn't show any error, but when I try to go to the MapsActivity, the app closes. It shows the app has stopped. What should I do now?

Comment: @SadmanKabirSoumik check the Error Log in Logcat,Update it over here