# Getting error in firebase code android How to resolve?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services-3.3.0

Getting below errors:

> Error:(209, 62) error: cannot access zzbgl
>   class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.qltech.ql.yupit"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 7
    versionName "7.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    build {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}
dependencies {
implementation  fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation  'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.28.0'
implementation  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
implementation  'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.2'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5"
implementation  'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.8.1@aar'
implementation  'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
implementation  'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
implementation  'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
implementation  'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
implementation  'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation  'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation  'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation  'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.6'
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation  'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
implementation  'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0'
implementation  'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
implementation  'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
implementation  'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.faruktoptas:FancyShowCaseView:1.0.1'
implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
implementation  'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation  "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 repositories {
mavenCentral()
 }
```

app.gradle;

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change all `compile` keywords to `implementation`. According to my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51841237/5246885)**, please comment/remove the following line of code:

```
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

And only use:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5"
```

Here is the official documentation regarding [Individual APIs and corresponding build.gradle descriptions](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

According to your edited question, please also change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
```

to

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
```

Comment: Getting Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.1" this error

Comment: Add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as the last line in your document and be sure to have `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` in your build.gradle (project) file. Your dragle also should be: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`.

Comment: still getting Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.1"

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the content of your both build.gradle files.

Comment: I see now. In this case, please see my **entire** edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185208/discussion-between-vishal-vaishnav-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: I used 11.4.0 version in all firebase and google gradle